# Starting jsreport service on a specific port through shell script

Tags: javascript, jsreport

I'm providing a library which uses `jsreport`. The server starts working by  the following shell script being run :

```
npm install jsreport

node node_modules/jsreport --init
```

The default port the service runs is `443`. But I want to run it on another port.

As I `npm install` it every time,  I don't want to manipulate the config file manually and every time, as its structure may change in later versions of `jsreport`. Is there any way to specify the port in shell script command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration can be specified in

- config file
- node shell arguments
- process environment variables
- directly in javascript in bootstrapper options

For your case you should type in shell

```
node server.js --httpsPort=5000
```

For the http port it would be

```
node server.js --httpPort=3000 --httpsPort=0
```

You need to set `httpsPort=0` otherwise jsreport starts listening on both ports and use http to respond with redirects to https.